# Vega lite highlighting data

Tags: vega-lite

I have an hconcat function in Vega lite displaying country and a score. I wanted to highlight some countries (changing the color of some and leaving the rest as it is) but when ever I use the color function either it gives me an error if it is outsite go hconcad or just highlights the countries I want in one graph but not display the rest:

With nothing:
[image]

with color in hconcat:
[image]

How can I do a highlight outside of the hconcat (or inside I can just repeated across all graphs), while leaving all the other data in the same color.

My code:

```
        {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanStein91/Info-vis/master/coffee.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "csv",
      "parse": {
        "Aroma": "number",
        "Flavor": "number",
        "Aftertaste": "number",
        "Acidity": "number",
        "Clean_Cup": "number",
        "Body": "number",
        "Balance": "number",
        "Uniformity": "number",
        "Cupper_Points": "number",
        "Sweetness": "number"
      }
    }
  },
"transform": [
        {
          "filter": "datum.Country_of_Origin"
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum.Aroma + datum.Flavor + datum.Aftertaste + datum.Acidity + datum.Sweetness + datum.Balance ",
          "as": "Taste_Points"
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum.Cupper_Points + datum.Clean_Cup + datum.Uniformity",
          "as": "Cup_Points"
        }
      ],
      "hconcat": [
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "Country_of_Origin",
              "type": "nominal",
              "sort": "-x"
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "Taste_Points",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "Country_of_Origin",
              "type": "nominal",
              "sort": "-x"
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "Cup_Points",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "Country_of_Origin",
              "type": "nominal",
              "sort": "-x"
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "Total_Cup_Points",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean"
            },
      "color": {
        "field": "Country_of_Origin",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain": [
            "Papua New Guinea",
            "Mauritius"
          ],
          "range": [
            "#8101FA",
            "#00C7A9"
          ]
        }
      }
          }
        }
      ],
      "config": {}
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code you have tried: it's difficult to guess from a screenshot what the problem might be. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: I added the main body of my code with the color bit, I want it to just highlight the two countries across all graphs while still displaying the other bars.

Comment: Please update your partial code snippet to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Again, it's quite difficult to help when we have to guess what code you're running.

Comment: added the beginning as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [Repeat Chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/repeat.html) along with a [Condition](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/condition.html) in the color encoding. The result might look something like this ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJFYAnMdlwFiZUifQB3BszbtWsZCfjK8yJXjpeqKQAIuhKAMo+jEoAnACMpACSSgBm3CIUjLCkGLA+JqReKSnIyAGwFGoaRmkmGHgWBoZGeACehMgWkPAVVc1GhOgm7o3V-ZAAgibcGF1KrKjsHn39RgBiYugU3CZzC0u76qtGEyn5unmdOJDzi8tHx5PwjJrMrXt3h2PNkADCYsgwgB9X6sQgfA4rVaQABC3E072ut0hD2hMPQmyU8CuUGR92+hkgAFUlIxaqg3hD8ccoKDCB0TECAArcaJ4WBUr40yDheylPBKZCwDlI-bLAkAXzGUogEoekDwdiUsHJFgA2mNgJAUowxPkuto8As6L9uKw-CZWkDuCkgQB5EyMJgqOWagndDHwVibHwGnTGqYzdBgADUYENxo2Wx2ofD-tQdFO53Ql1jEYTE2erzaafjdF5-MFwtzRoT6Mx2KgqMJKa6ABUUz5may-BzpdWmj94J7vTocZB0yawQzm2zYCXjf9AUoQWCJwmSWSdhS2lCayLaWDR63INKNABdeUmZAdHTqyANy7b9lqTeEa8c1RQOvcXRiWf3lljyCHjSQWAdPAow-BgJgANZdOwQxrpAvheK8SjUMB4yImAWo6sgYiaF0prmoqVo2vajrOreCrtP2SgzNEGKkYoJgNNcIgAB6QK60IsfoBI1IwmHYfokDHqeDFQIJgINGxjxtB0XQAI6sGEeDMDojBUGuPzoNQ1DHrQvrXKg067qsEldtwYg7Mh0IUBirD9pcmHsGINlqYSXhKNmPAqJxNItEKwmdt52o8VhOFmhaBG2g6TrRM50LKMgdopOeTLoIQ8lgAAcsg9hgAA4qw0SAqRACy6CmMwjBuD+XGGMZjwYcF1y4WF1oRcR0XVtCUkUVRSg0R14wIBiOL+dymhBtFOBqpAyWpcGmXZXlBWYE+kAlWVimVb+3mEkq1A4lNADEAAccQAAxxGsEykQdp2nb8ADsEwxFV20yscb3NB9YBvVKEpAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanStein91/Info-vis/master/coffee.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "csv",
      "parse": {
        "Aroma": "number",
        "Flavor": "number",
        "Aftertaste": "number",
        "Acidity": "number",
        "Clean_Cup": "number",
        "Body": "number",
        "Balance": "number",
        "Uniformity": "number",
        "Cupper_Points": "number",
        "Sweetness": "number"
      }
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.Country_of_Origin"},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Aroma + datum.Flavor + datum.Aftertaste + datum.Acidity + datum.Sweetness + datum.Balance ",
      "as": "Taste_Points"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Cupper_Points + datum.Clean_Cup + datum.Uniformity",
      "as": "Cup_Points"
    }
  ],
  "repeat": ["Taste_Points", "Cup_Points", "Total_Cup_Points"],
  "spec": {
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
      "y": {"field": "Country_of_Origin", "type": "nominal", "sort": "-x"},
      "x": {
        "field": {"repeat": "repeat"},
        "type": "quantitative",
        "aggregate": "mean"
      },
      "color": {
        "value": "steelblue",
        "condition": {
          "test": {
            "field": "Country_of_Origin",
            "oneOf": ["Papua New Guinea", "Mauritius"]
          },
          "field": "Country_of_Origin",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": ["Papua New Guinea", "Mauritius"],
            "range": ["#8101FA", "#00C7A9"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]